# how to make my application support for all devices resolution

Tags: java, android

I have develop an app which runs very well in my emulator and in my Samsung device. But when I test it in the Motorola emulator, which I have downloaded in my android SDK, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me out to figure this problem of supporting multiple devices?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is or what symptoms you observe. Please be more descriptive. What have you tried? Have you checked logcat output?

Comment: Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

Comment: Are you trying to load the app on lower/higher SDK version emulator than what your app supports (<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />)

Answer (score 1):

You can add following code in your AndroidManifest.xml to support different screens.

```
   <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true" 
              android:anyDensity="true">
```

Check this for more details http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what is your problem, but often if the resolution changes the layout problems can be many.
One of them is the unit used in the xml of the layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textSize="13px"
                android:paddingLeft="10px" />
```

in this case for example textSize is in pixel, which can be small or bigger depending from the DPI of te screen.
You can change this specify other units of measurements like points:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textSize="13pt"
                android:paddingLeft="10pt" />
```

put more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I depends a lot on what your problem is but if the problem is that your app won't install try adding this to your AndroidManifest

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

SDK 1.5 did not support the drawable sub-folders (`/hdpi`, `/mdpi` & `/sdpi`) for the different resolutions. If you need your App to work on all SDKs, you should put all your drawables in the `/drawable` folder (not its subfolders).